# mySQL column 'id' in field list is ambigous

Tags: mysql, sql

The code below is giving me the error:

> column 'id' in field list is ambiguous.

I added the `productr2011` to it and it started doing that. If I take out the `product2011` from the query then it works just fine.

```
SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
FROM productr
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
GROUP BY itemName

UNION

SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
FROM productr2010, productr2011
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY SumOf DESC;
```

Why does it work with just the `product2010` and not when it has `product2010, product2011`?

**Update**

I am just trying to combine old archive records to a search. Hints why I am adding all data from 2010 and 2011 (usually the query dates should be of 2011 and not 2012) :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure you want to do a join between `product2010` and `product2011`?  I am not sure about your exact requirement, but this maybe what you are looking for:

```
    SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
    FROM productr
    WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
    GROUP BY itemName
UNION
    SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
    FROM productr2010
    WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
    GROUP BY itemName
UNION
    SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
    FROM productr2011
    WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
    GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY SumOf DESC;
```

Answer (score 5):

If both `productr2010`, and `productr2011` have an `id` field, then you'll have to formally qualify which one to select:

```
SELECT productr2010.id
```

Even if you do that, though, I doubt that you're on the right track with your query. Why would you want to cross join the two tables? Since this looks like a table historisation, I'm guessing you should add yet another `UNION` clause, to "unify" `productr2010`, and `productr2011`, rather than joining them. In other words, do something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM productr
...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM productr2010
...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM productr2011
...
```

Even then, I think the query you *do want* is this (preventing duplicate entries per `itemName` among the three tables):

```
SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
FROM (
  SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, itemsSold FROM productr     UNION ALL
  SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, itemsSold FROM productr2011 UNION ALL
  SELECT id, itemName, itemRUDate, itemsSold FROM productr2010  
) AS subquery
WHERE itemRUDate >= '2012/03/03' AND itemRUDate <= '2012/03/03'
GROUP BY itemName
ORDER BY Sum(itemsSold) DESC;
```

I'm still a bit confused why you would want select any arbitrary `id` and `itemRUDate` values from your grouped subqueries, but that would be another question...

Comment: Although your answer is just like nikhil500 - nikhil500 was a few minutes ahead of you :o) But thanks all the same!

Comment: @StealthRT: Good for nikhil500, even if I think you're reading the timestamps a bit wrong ;-). Nevertheless, check my updated answer. I think your query is still not entirely correct...

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which table the id column is coming from.

Either:

```
   SELECT productr2010.id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
```

OR

```
   SELECT productr2011.id, itemName, itemRUDate, Sum(itemsSold) AS SumOf
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, bluefeet.