# I got this error in teradata "SELECT Failed 3809 column"xxx' is ambiguos"

Tags: sql, teradata

Here is my query

```
select "column_names from 2 tables" from table_1, table_2
and table_1.column_1 in
(select column_1 from table_1 where column_2='hsgdv');
```

One of the columns selected in showing the error that it is ambiguous

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL column 'id' in field list is ambigous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928516/mysql-column-id-in-field-list-is-ambigous)

Comment: is the column "xxx" exists in more than one table?

Comment: 1) please learn ansi sql join syntax. The join syntax you are using hasn’t been considered good practice for 30+ years 2) Your SQL is not valid and is obviously not the actual SQL you are running, please update your question with the actual SQL

Comment: If table_1 and table_2 both have a column named col_x then you can't just refer to col_x. You have to qualify as table_1.col_x or table_2.col_x to remove ambiguity.  Particularly if the table name is long, you may want to assign an alias / correlation name in the FROM clause, e.g. `FROM table_1 AS a` and then use `a.col_x`

Comment: Always qualify your column names, not only does it prevent this error, it makes debugging a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Probably table_1 and table_2 has same column names. select column names explicity with tables like:

```
select table_1.col1, table_1.col2, table_2.col1, ....from 
table_1, table_2
    and table_1.column_1 in
    (select column_1 from table_1 where column_2='hsgdv');
```